# How to get only the first component of each hidden vector generated by LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following implementation of LSTM:

```
num_units = 2
lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units = num_units)

timesteps = 100
num_input = 1

# define a computational graph
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, timesteps, num_input])
x = tf.unstack(X, timesteps, 1)
outputs, states = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

As far as I understood `outputs` contains a sequence of hidden vectors `h` generated by the LSTM. In more details it is a list in which elements corresponds to the time steps and each element ins a 2D tensor in which the axis 0 corresponds to the batch index and the axis 1 corresponds to the dimensionality of the hidden vectors.

Now, I would like to take the first component of each hidden vector (to combine it with the corresponding input vector x). How can I do it?

**ADDED**

More formally, I would need to take something like: `outputs[:, :, 0]` . However, I am not sure if something like that is going to work since  outputs is not a 3D tensor, it is a list of 2D tensors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a static RNN (btw, static RNN are available in core TensorFlow now through [`tf.nn.static_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/static_rnn)), then you could do it like this:

```
num_units = 2
lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units = num_units)

timesteps = 100
num_input = 1

# define a computational graph
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, timesteps, num_input])
x = tf.unstack(X, timesteps, 1)
outputs, states = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm, x, dtype=tf.float32)
outputs0 = [out[:, 0] for out in outputs]
```

If you want to have those values as a tensor instead of a list of tensors, you would do:

```
outputs0 = tf.stack(outputs0, axis=1)
```

The other option would be to use a dynamic RNN to get a tensor as output:

```
num_units = 2
lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units = num_units)

timesteps = 100
num_input = 1

# define a computational graph
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, timesteps, num_input])
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm, X, dtype=tf.float32)
outputs0 = outputs[:, :, 0]
```